# Highcharts - bubble diagram need smaller bubbles infront of bigger

Tags: highcharts, overlapping, bubble-chart

We are using the Highchart bubble diagram, however when bubble x and y are on the same place in the diagram and bubble y is smaller there is no way to neither see nor much less click the smaller bubble.

Is there any way to plot the bigger bubbles first and then plot the smaller ones on top? Or a setting which says that smaller ones always are on top of the bigger ones?

Comment: Can we make the assumption that several small ones completely covering a bigger one is acceptable?

Comment: Unfortunately in the Highcharts this kind of resize is not possible. So you need to declare a "z" parameter manually. http://jsfiddle.net/e6qyLt9b/

Meantime you can post your suggestion in our uservoice here: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/

Comment: Making bubbles of different size on a bubble chart without any (apparent) reason doesn't sound like a good idea. People might mistake it for another dimension in the chart.

Answer (score 1):

Just sort the series data in **descending order** and pass it to the highcharts.

So that, the bigger bubbles will be plotted first and then the smaller ones, thereby the user will be able to hover on smaller as well as bigger bubbles.

Tried this in my project, and it's working perfectly fine !